# if $K\cap \text{Ker } f=0$ ($K+\text{Ker }f=M$ resp.) then $f_{\left|K\right.}:K\longrightarrow N$ is monomorphism (epimorphism resp.)

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $f$ be $R$-epimorphism from $R$-module $M$ to $R$-module $N$ and $K$ be submodule of $M$.
Prove that if $K\cap \text{Ker }f=0$ ($K+\text{Ker }f=M$ resp.) then $f_{\left|K\right.}:K\longrightarrow N$ is monomorphism (epimorphism resp.)

Comment: What is $R$? A ring or a field? What have you tried?

Comment: @BISHD: It doesn't matter. OP: What have you tried?

Comment: @nik Thanks for repeating my question ;-P Actually, questions have to be complete, so the specification of $R$ is mandatory even if one can make a reasonable assumption about $R$ (not to be $0$ for example).

Comment: @BISHD: "Thanks for repeating my question": you do realize that there is a little pencil showing that you edited your comment...?

Comment: @BISHD: As for specifying $R$, the question is true for any ring $R$. You don't have to make any assumptions. And it's clear from the context that $R$ is a ring.

Comment: @nik I don't want to argue with you. I was inserting the "What have you tried"-comment before reading your comment (2 minutes before as you can see btw.). As we're both mathematicians we agree on being exact is necessary for an OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f_{\mid K}$ is a monomorphism if and only if $\ker f_{\mid K} = 0$. But $\ker f_{\mid K} = \ker f$ and $K \cap \ker f = 0$. So this gives you the first claim.

For the second claim, $f_{\mid K}$ is an epimorphism, iff. $f_{\mid K}(K) = N$. But $f$ is an epimorphism $M \longrightarrow N$, so there exists a preimage $m$ for every $n \in N$ with $f(m) = n$. If $n \neq 0$ this preimage $m$ is already in $K$, since $K + \ker f = M$ and therefore $f_{\mid K}$ is an epimorphism.

Hope that helped you.